# Is it possible to run another mobile application within your application?

Tags: android, view

This is an odd question, but is there any way to run two separate applications inside one app? So, for example, run another application in a view inside of another app? Is this possible? If so, how is this done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But that's what the Intent system is for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android launch app inside view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349749/android-launch-app-inside-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WeChat has hundreds of Mini-Programs can only open via WeChat apps. But that mini-programs is web-based view. Here the official video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKcdUT3ZSwA .

Comment: Thats a great response and more inline of what I was looking for when I asked this question. Somehow it became an Intent issue. Great answer! This should be the accepted one.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I guess you can change the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

This may be done although it may go against the recommended way of doing things in Android

[Android launch app inside view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349749/android-launch-app-inside-view)

[How to create android app with app widget in single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038385/how-to-create-android-app-with-app-widget-in-single-application)

An easier alternative may be to launch an intent with the package address:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setPackage("com.otherapp.package");
startActivity(i);
```

[Launching Android app, within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073671/launching-android-app-within-an-app)

[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

However, please note that, technically, the other app is still in its own process although you it appears to function within the original app.

[Launch another application INSIDE an application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451139/launch-another-application-inside-an-application-in-android)